# Use Left/Right Arrow Keys on Button Click event VS2008

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use the left and right arrow keys to do performclick on my back and next buttons. Here's the code:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Left Then
        Me.cmdPrevQ.PerformClick()
        Return True
    End If

    If keyData = Keys.Right Then
        Me.cmdNextQ.PerformClick()
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

I want this function to only work as soon as I click on a listview item and not on formload but I don't know how to do that :(

I tried the KeyDown event for my listview but what happens is even if I haven't clicked on anything in my listview and I press on the left or right arrow keys, it gives me an error as my next and back buttons rely on the items inside my listview.

Please help

Comment: Why not just check `YourListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0` in `KeyDown`?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! :)